# Python args parsing issue when do Run Python File

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python is not parsing arguments when I run the script however it works fine in debug mode. Not sure what am I missing?

```
import argparse
"""
Parse arguments passed during startup
"""
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Blockchain full node.')
parser.add_argument('--node', required=True,type=str, help='Address of node to connect. If not will init fist node.')
parser.add_argument('--port', required=True, type=int, help='Port on which run the node.')
parser.add_argument('--webport', required=True, type=int, help='Port on which run the node.')
parser.add_argument('--memPoolport', required=True, type=int, help='Port on which run the node.')
parser.add_argument('--BTCsimulation', required=True, type=str, help='Port on which run the node.')

args = parser.parse_args()

local_address = args.node
local_port    = args.port
webport       = args.webport
memPoolport   = args.memPoolport
BTCsimulation = args.BTCsimulation
```

Here is the launch.json file and I can see a warning under type:python. Below is the warning message.
**Configured debug type 'python' is installed but not supported in this environment.(2)**

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "args": ["--node","127.0.0.1",
                "--port","5900",
                "--webport","5901",
                "--memPoolport","5902",
                "--BTCsimulation","True"],
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the exact error that I get when run this script.

[image]

Comment: Please include your code here, not on images.

Comment: @PedroMaia code added. Thanks

Comment: Is this for VSCode?

Comment: To my knowledge, you can't run scripts with arguments using "the play button" in VS Code, with out 1) running in debug mode like you did, 2) typing out the command yourself in the terminal. However, if you type it out once, you can use the arrow keys to scroll though the command history so you don't have to type it out every time.

Comment: Thanks... I have used config.ini file instead of passing arguments in launch.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having a similar issue, same error message. In my case it is regarding the "python" type configuration defined in the launch.json file. Here's a couple options:

1. Downgrade to an earlier version
2. Upgrade to VS Code Insider version 1.62.2 (or later)
3. Wait until December for the fix to come out

This seems to be a new problem in vscode's Python extension ([issue 136712](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/136712)) and recently fix in the latest VS Code Insider, but several comments show that downgrading resolves the issue. I don't know enough about the workings of VS Code and the extensions to understand exactly what is happening here; the extension and API are obviously linked closely, but seems strange (to me, anyway) a bug in one requires a fix in the other.

The problem came about from this "improvement" added back in September, which broke the Python Debug configuration. See issue [17493](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/17493) "Implement 'when' clause for debugger contribution points to turn them off on virtual workspaces".

Here's the link to download VS Code Insider (not recommended, but here it is anyway, I used it and it seems to work): https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/

I hope this helps. I am still looking into this and if I come up with anything substantial (or realize I'm pointing you in a bad direction), I'll be back.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you Robert that explains why it was working fine earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this issue after the December update.  Here's how I fixed your issue noted #2

I had this same problem, the easiest way for me to fix it was just to go to the Python file in the explorer, right click, and choose "run current file in interactive window". After that selection, VSCode prompted me that "X,Y,Z, will need to be installed and configured", I did, and then everything worked just fine!